# Chat-room one-boxing for Google n-grams

Tags: feature-request

The Chat room can one-box lots of things, like wikipedia links and youtube videos, making nice neat messages.

In ELU chat it would be very useful to be able to one-box Google ngram links, to show the graph as returned by Google.

I'd like to post a link like this:

> https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=springtime%2Csummertime%2Cwintertime%2Cfalltime%2C+autumntime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspringtime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csummertime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwintertime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfalltime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cautumntime%3B%2Cc0

and have it do this:
[image]

And while we're at it, it would be very handy if that could happen automatically on the main site too.

Comment: So, one pragmatic issue is that the NGrams page doesn't really display an *image* that can be automatically uploaded to `i.stack.imgur.com`. The actual graph is an [SVG element](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp). In order to automatically grab the graph you'd have to load the page, convert the SVG element into an image, and then upload the image so it can be displayed in chat. The good news is that a whole bunch of other people want to do [something similar](http://www.bing.com/search?q=converting+svg+element+to+image) so... a solution probably exists out there somewhere.

Comment: Given that SVG is fully supported in pretty much every browser, it might not be too hard to scrape the svg and just include it as-is. The chat messages are already HTML-formatted blobs, as evidenced by the fact that you can quote your own message in itself.

Answer (score 3):

Just bumping this up again, maybe technology evolved.